# How to edit page content in Drupal

Tags: drupal-7

I've just taken over as a developer for an already existing website made in Drupal 7. And somehow I'm finding it hard to change the content on one of the pages.

https://www.wheelandbarrow.com.au/gift-cards

I'm wanting to change the text at the bottom of the page under Terms and Conditions.

1. Cant find it ANYWHERE inside the Drupal CMS, it doesnt appear under content, pages, modules or nodes etc... I've literally been searching everywhere for hours.
2. Figured it might be hard coded so I've also done half a dozen keyword searched within my repository code - but no luck.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you in advance,

Craig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is panel, look at source code.
Go to the admin/structure/pages/edit/node_view
I think that it is correct panel, find your variant and edit custom block text.